# Can't figure out how to return input

Tags: python, string, input

Basically user has to input their name like `jOhn JhOnson`
and i have to return it as `John Jhonson`
but if the user has 3 names like `jonny jon jony`
I have to return it like `Jonny-Jon Jony`
and i have no idea how

Comment: Clearly you don't have much knowledge on `String manipulation`.

You should start by reading some documentation about it, and focus on Substrings because it will answer your question.

Substrings documentation:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/manipstrings.html

Comment: Can I ask _why_ you're looking to change user input? The standard  for this sort of thing is to accept whatever a user inputs without editing it in any way.

Comment: It's for school and I'm like stupidly obsessed but stuck on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a string tokenizer to count the number of names you have. Then you can easily manipulate each token and then append them altogether for your return value. I can't really help you beyond that without knowing what language you are using.

Comment: im using python, i know i need to use .split() and .capitalize() but i just can't figure out how to code it so it would count how many names are in the input and if there are 3 then it inserts "-" between first and second while capitalizing every first letter

Comment: iterate over your list of strings and use a count variable to count how many strings you have. The list is ordered so if you pass "jonny jon johnson", list[0]='jonny' list[1]='jon' list[2]='johnson'. So to append them you would just use list[0] + "-" + list[1] + " " + list[2]. Also I would suggest capitalizing the tokens before appending them together

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code for your purpose

```
inp = [i.capitalize() for i in input().split()]
print(*inp)
```